# Strange behaviour of $parse, if passed string starts with number

Tags: angularjs

In a directive I want to use the $parse service to work with a passed in  parameter.
Then I have this behaviour which I do not understand:

- depending on the nature of a passed in string, I get an

> Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error 
>   (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=b&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=2&p3=1b&p4=b)

My Code:

```
console.log($parse('hallo')); // fine
console.log($parse('123'));   // fine
console.log($parse('b1'));    // fine
console.log($parse('1b'));    // error!
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in the definition of `$parse`:

> Converts Angular **expression** into a function.

The first three strings are valid expressions: 1st and 3rd are valid variable identifiers, the 2nd is a literal number. The 4th however is *NOT* a valid expression (e.g. identifiers cannot start with number, numbers cannot have letters and so on). Therefore you get the parse error.